# How can you center a logo on a Kalium Theme on Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've tried centering my site logo with CSS, but nothing changes. Is there a way to center the site logo on the header when using a Kalium theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the Header you are using. But as far as I see all of them are built with a `flex` layout.

So to give you an example for the main layout: https://demo.kaliumtheme.com/main/

In this case you could really just set the `flex-direction` to `column` and the `justify-content` to `center`:

```css
header.main-header .logo-and-menu-container {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

In addition I would give the logo some `margin-bottom`:

```css
.header-logo.logo-image {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Et voila, looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
header.main-header .logo-and-menu-container
 {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}
```